# Game ranking system: Problems adding email

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm creating a script to sort winners and losers of a game system. I have a list of players who have defeated other players, and those players get credit for any player who has been defeated by someone they have defeated. This script finds those players and gives the top level winners credit.

I am scraping a CSV file to find people who were defeated by the people defeated by the top level winners, then appending that data and sort it.

The script works fine with one exception; for some reason it is only copying one seemingly random email address and applying it to all rows in the output. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Input:

```
 Winners,Losers,Email
 John,Amanda,amanda@
 Mark,Eddy,eddy@
 Amanda,Chad,chad@
 Becky,Michael,michael@
 Michael,Steve,steve@
 Eddy,Fred,fred@
 Michael,Stuart,stuart@
 Edwardo,Patricia,patricia@
 Michael,Buzz,buzz@
 Mark,Charlie,charlie@ 
 Amanda,Brandon,brandon@
 Brandon,Dirk,dirk@
```

Current (bad) output:

```
 Winners,Losers,Brandon@
 John,Amanda,Brandon@
 John,Chad,Brandon@
 John,Brandon,Brandon@
 John,Dirk,Brandon@
 Mark,Eddy,Brandon@
 Mark,Fred,Brandon@
 Mark,Charlie,Brandon@
 Amanda,Chad,Brandon@
 Becky,Michael,Brandon@
 Becky,Steve,Brandon@
 Michael,Steve,Brandon@
 Michael,Stuart,Brandon@
 Michael,Buzz,Brandon@
 Eddy,Fred,Brandon@
 Edwardo,Patricia,Brandon@
 Amanda,Brandon,Brandon@
 Brandon,Dirk,Brandon@
```

Desired output = Current output but with the proper loser's email address.

```
 import csv

 def find_losers(winner, results):
     for loser in results.get(winner, ()):
         yield loser
         for child in find_losers(loser, results):
             yield child

 def find_email(loser, results):
     for loser_email in results.get(loser, ()):
         yield loser_email
         for child in find_email(loser_email, results):
             yield child


     for loser_email in results.get(winner, ()):
         yield loser_email
         for child in find_losers(loser_email, results):
             yield child

 with open('output.csv', 'w') as f1, open('input.csv') as f2:
     reader = csv.reader(f2)
     writer = csv.writer(f1)
     writer.writerow(next(reader))
     results = {}
     for winner, loser, loser_email in reader:
         results.setdefault(winner, []).append(loser),                
 (loser_email)
     for winner in results:
         for loser in find_losers(winner, results):
             writer.writerow((winner, loser, loser_email))
```

Comment: In this example, how did you get `@Brandon` (with upper-case 'B') as file output when that spelling does not appear in the input file?

Comment: Typed it up manually and hit the shift button.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you expect to have *different* emails there.  Look at your output loop:

```
for winner in results:
    for loser in find_losers(winner, results):
        writer.writerow((winner, loser, loser_email))
```

`loser_email` is a loop invariant: you don't change it anywhere in the loop.  It has whatever value remains from the last iteration of the previous loop.  This will be that last email processed from the input file.

If you want the *corresponding* email for each loser, you have to store them as you read them, placing the emails in a corresponding position.  This is done easily enough with your given list structure, as dict, or a PANDAS data frame.

Also, I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do:

```
    for winner, loser, loser_email in reader:
        results.setdefault(winner, []).append(loser),                
(loser_email)
```

That dangling expression `(loser_email)` simply gets evaluated and then ignored -- you don't do anything with the value.  Perhaps you meant:

```
    for winner, loser, loser_email in reader:
        results.setdefault(winner, []).append([loser, loser_email])
```

... which would append a 2-element list to the winner's entry in `results`.  *This* would give you the information to extract the email later.

Comment: I fixed the dangling expression, thank you for that. Would you be able to get me pointed in the right direction on using dict to grab the data from each line instead of just outputting the last email read?

Comment: There are various ways to do it; work through a tutorial on dictionaries?
I'd use the player as the key, email as the value.